# Maximum sum Sequence such that no two elements are adjacent

Tags: algorithm, dynamic-programming

My implementation of max sum is below but i need **sequence** which is giving max sum i looked on `google` and `stackoverflow` but nowhere sequence is output.

```
public int maxSum(int arr[]) {
     int excl = 0;
     int incl = arr[0];
     for (int i = 1; i < arr.length; i++) {
       int temp = incl;
       incl = Math.max(excl + arr[i], incl);
       excl = temp;
     }
     return incl;
}
```

So 3 2 7 10 should return (3 and 10) or 3 2 5 10 7 should return (3, 5 and 7) or {5, 5, 10, 100, 10, 5} will return (5, 100 and 5) or {1, 20, 3} will return 20
i exactly want this [problem](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/maximum-sum-such-that-no-two-elements-are-adjacent/) solution but return value i need is sequence of elements included in max sum instead of max sum value

Comment: adjacent means equals?

Comment: no ajacent means left and right side element like in sequence 2 5 4 7 8 2 and 4 are adjacent of 5

Comment: So in array [2 3 4 4 5]  -> 2, 3, 4 is such a sequence, right?

Comment: no 2,4,5 will be that sequence because 2+4+5=11 and 2,4,5 are not adjacent also

Comment: Please check this one, it might fix the problem. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55688939/maximum-sum-of-non-adjacent-elements-of-an-array-to-be-printed

Answer (score 0):

You mean that in this array: [1,3,4,2,4,7,5,3] , calculate [1+4+4+5] and [3+2+7+3]
and return the bigger one?

If you do so, this is my algorithm:

```
public int maxSum(int arr[]) {
  int sum1 = 0;
  int sum2 = 0;
  for(int i = 0; i < arr.length; i+=2)
    sum1 += arr[i];
  for(int i = 1; i < arr.length; i+=2)
    sum2 += arr[i];

  return Math.max(sum1, sum2);
}
```

Or this one:

```
public int maxSum(int arr[]) {
  int sum1 = 0;
  int sum2 = 0;
  for(int i = 0; i < arr.length; i+=2)
    sum1 += arr[i];
    try {sum2 += arr[i + 1];} catch(ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException e){}
  }
  return Math.max(sum1, sum2);
}
```

Comment: no this is not correct answer see example i added more example

Answer (score 0):

Looks similar to Longest Increasing Fragment problem(Top Down approach.)
Instead of having length of sequence, you can return sum of it. Also, instead of skipping one, skipping two to avoid adjacent elements.

Comment: yes top down approach is used in this dp problem but i dont want sum i want sequence

Comment: maintain a cache that hold pointer to the previous index and a current maximum sum. After you find the maximum sum, you can do back tracking to find its sequence.

Answer (score 0):

**#simplest and clean solution**

```
 public int maxSubsetSumNoAdjacent(int[] arr) {


  if(arr.length == 0){
   return 0;
  }
if(arr.length == 1){
 return arr[0];
}

int a =arr[0];
int b= 0;
int c =a;

int i=1;
while(i<arr.length){

a=arr[i]+b;
b=Math.max(c,b);
c=a;


i++;

}



    return Math.max(a,b);
  }
```